# Is there a way to compare formatted value by NumberFormat?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, dart-intl

I'm creating unit tests for a currency format using [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) last version `0.16.1`.
My formatter is: `final currencyFormat = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'pt_BR');`

My expected result is: `var expected = r'R$ 1,00';`. And I applied my formatter to value `1.0` in this way: `var formatted = currencyFormat.format(1.0)` resulting in `R$ 1,00`.

When I test two values using an `expect(formatted, expected)`, it show me that the results are not the same.

```
Expected: 'R$ 1,00'
  Actual: 'R$ 1,00'
   Which: is different.
          Expected: R$ 1,00
            Actual: R$ 1,00
                      ^
           Differ at offset 2
```

Well, I had take some time to discover that the runes of two strings have one character diff.

expected runes: `(82, 36, 32, 49, 44, 48, 48)`

formatted runes: `(82, 36, 160, 49, 44, 48, 48)`

My question is: if is using a Non-breaking space when formatting, how can I avoid this error when there is no documentation talking about it?

Answer (score 0):

Until now, the only way I achieved was put unicode character to my expected string: `var expected = 'R\$\u{00A0}1,00';`.

This is not a good solution because if we have many formatters inside app and test all that use Non-breaking space we have to put in our expected value the ASCII code.